# replace parenthesis in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

How do you replace parenthesis with javascript.

I have a format like this:

```
(14.233,72.456),(12.4566,45.345),(12.456,13.567)
```

How can I get a format like given below:

```
14.233,72.456#12.4566,45.345#12.456,13.567
```

I have tried the following:

```
bounds = bounds.replace(/\)\,\(/g,'#');
bounds = bounds.replace(/\(/g,'');
bounds = bounds.replace(/\)/,'');
```

Comment: Those are called parenthesis, just FYI. Anyways, what have you tried?

Comment: @RohitJain: "Parentheses" ("es" at the end), in the plural. One parenthesis, two parentheses.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder hehe. I often get those wrong :)

Comment: Your code is fine and does what you want - what's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this (matches only float numbers) :

```
var s = '(14.233,72.456),(12.4566,45.345),(12.456,13.567)';
bounds = s.match(/\d+\.\d+,\d+\.\d+/g).join('#');
```

`s.match(/\d+\.\d+,\d+\.\d+/g)` returns :

```
['14.233,72.456', '12.4566,45.345', '12.456,13.567']
```

In addition, you might need to deal with an empty string :

```
bounds = (s.match(/\d+\.\d+,\d+\.\d+/g) || []).join('#');
```

Answer (score 2):

Splitting the string up by the delimiters and join them with your new delimiter:

```
var data = "(14.233,72.456),(12.4566,45.345),(12.456,13.567)";
data = data.slice(1, -1).split('),(').join('#');
```

Or using RegEx:

```
var data = "(14.233,72.456),(12.4566,45.345),(12.456,13.567)";
data = data.slice(1, -1).replace(/\),\(/g, '#');
```

Comment: shouldn't that be `data.length-1` in substring?

Comment: Rohit is right you can't get correct value with data.length-2

Comment: I simply would go with `.slice(1, -1)` :-) Indeed, `-2` would have to be used with `substr`, not `substring`.

Comment: @RohitJain thanks, stupid error. Bergi, thank you too, forgot about `.slice` ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = "(14.233,72.456),(12.4566,45.345),(12.456,13.567)";
var str = string.substring(1, string.length-1).split('),(').join('#');

alert(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, which is almost the same as your code:

```
bounds = bounds.replace(/\),\(/g,'#').replace(/^\(|\)$/g,'');
```

See here the code working: http://jsfiddle.net/K8ECj/

[Edited to eliminate capture]

Comment: What's the capturing group for?

Comment: @Bergi - changed the answer, thanks (I tried to replace the parentheses with something else first for testing...)

Answer (score -2):

You can use .replace("(", "").replace(")", "");